# Draw many pixel points android canvas or opengl?

Tags: java, android, canvas, opengl-es

I'm trying to implement my own mirroring protocol.
I'm using websockets to retrieve a compressed pixels buffer. After I decompress this buffer I got a big array of position with color that I should display.

I'm using canvas with a for loop on a huge arraylist (2 millions elements) in onDraw like following :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    for (int i = 0; i < this.pixelsList.size(); i++) { //SIZE = 2.073.600 pixels
        canvas.drawPoint(this.pixelsList.get(i).getPosition().x, this.pixelsList.get(i).getPosition().y, this.pixelsList.get(i).getPaint());
    }
}
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to display this huge packet.
I was on OpenGL ES but I did not find any way to display one pixel in one position.. Maybe should I take a look with OpenCV ?

Comment: It might be better to create a BufferedImage (copying the pixelList into the Raster), and then just draw the image.

Comment: Yes, buffered image will take care of most of this for you (or it should at least). You can even use parts if ImageIO for compression and data transfer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
Please can you provide me some samples of BufferedImage ? If I want to draw on a SurfaceView.

Comment: 2Millions not 2Billions. I was scared.

Comment: Sorry ! :D Post edited !

Comment: I would be faster if you use the pixel buffer as a texture and render it once. You don't need to render each pixel, do you?

Comment: How to do this ? I am not that good with OpenGL, if someone can provide me a sample of how to do this, it would be very nice! Thank you

Comment: @DevAndroid I answered the question but if you ask whole use of OpenGL, It is better to read this http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/

Comment: Perfect thank you !! I will check for this I mark it as resolved.

Comment: @DevAndroid you don't need to study glsl(shader) there just use a default shader for texture like gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, texCoordinate);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't dereference each pixel address and use a texture in OpenGL. This might be the fastest way.

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture[texture_id].texture_width, texture[texture_id].texture_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelsList);
```

or if it's frequently updated

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,  **pixelsList**);
```

Comment: Thank you !!
Yes it will be very frequently updated.
I did not understand this line : glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
I can't put 0 as last parameter, it waits a Buffer of pixels. How can I build it ?

Comment: @DevAndroid the last parameter of glTexSubImage2D is an address of image in this case. If it is a video frame so it must be more frequently updated, then you need to use PBO with glTexSubImage2D.

Comment: It still does not display anything. I filled out a ByteBuffer object of pixels A R G B and passed it in glTexImage2D. Nothing appears... Can I show you ?

Comment: @DevAndroid Yes please show me. Did you draw a rectangle by the way?